# Why is this blitting two times?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a microsoft paint like program using pygame, however im running into an issue while trying to create "stickers".

my sticker code looks like:

```
if canvasRect.collidepoint(mx,my) and mb[0]:
        for j in range(12,len(tools)):
            screen.set_clip(canvasRect)
            if tool==tools[j]:
                for i in range(len(stampNames)):
                    stickers=image.load(stampNames[i])
                    wid=stickers.get_width() 
                    hei=stickers.get_height()
                    if mb[0]:
                        screen.blit(stickers,(mx-wid//2,my-hei//2))
```

and i have two lists related to the code above being:

```
tools=["brush","eraser","pencil","line","load","save","spraypaint","bucket","clear","ellipse","fillellipse","box","fillbox","Lewy","Neuer"]
```

and:

```
stampNames=["icons/lewy.png","icons/neuer.png"]
```

how could i make stop it from "blitting" two times and prevent it from blitting multiple times when i update the list with more.

Comment: As it stands, replicating your issue is terribly hard, probably unanswerable. I am not sure either of what you mean by "blitting" or "creating stickers". Using something like stackblitz, codesanbox or replit may increase your odds of getting an answer and not getting downvoted.

Comment: What is `mb` ? As @ferreiradev said, right now your question is not answerable. Try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Side-note : You can make your code a bit easier to read by using for each loops. Also you probably don't want to load your image every time you need to blit it

Comment: I think your approach is not good.  Instead of `blit()`ting the sticker on a mouse-click (guess), store the sticker ID (name?) and the position in a **list**.  Then at paint-time draw all the stickers stored in the list.  Anyway, as for the multiple-blits - the code is looping through *all* stamps, blitting them.  Why do you expect that *not* to happen?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to determine what it is you want from the small snippet of code, but I'm guessing the desire is:

> If the mouse-button-1 is clicked `mb[0]`, draw a "stamp" (AKA "sticker") at the mouse-cordinates `mx`,`my`.

It looks like your code is drawing the image as the click is made.  As I said in a comment, this is not a good approach.  PyGame is an "event driven" system, and generally this means the code needs to react to user-input events to update an internal model, and *then* render that model to the window.

So in terms of clicking the mouse to place a "stamp", it would be better to simply remember the stamp-type and the position clicked.  These can then be painted later in the update loop.

But first we need a list of stickers to stamp.  Here's a snippet of code that will iterate over a list of sticker-names, creating a python dictionary of images.  So later `stickers[ "sticker1" ]` gets an Image:

```
stickers = {}      # dictionary of stickers, by name
for sticker_name in [ "sticker1", "sticker2", "sticker3" ]:
    filename += sticker_name + ".png"
    try:
        sticker_image = pygame.image.load( filename ).convert_alpha()
        stickers[ sticker_name ] = sticker_image
    except:
        print( "Failed to load sticker [" + sticker_name + "]" )
```

Probably you have some method of remembering the user's selected sticker-name.  I'm going to assume this is the variable `current_sticker`.

```
current_sticker = stickers.keys()[0]    # default to first sticker
```

Now handle the mouse-click by remembering the sticker name, and the mouse-position into the list `placed_stickers`:

```
placed_stickers = []   # initially empty

# ...

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False 
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:    # mouse button released
            if event.button == 1:
                mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                sticker_position = stickers[current_sticker].get_rect( topleft=(mx,my) )
                placed_stickers.append( [ sticker_position, current_sticker ] )
```

So in this manner, when mouse-button-1 is released, the `placed_stickers` list will get a new list-entry like [ [100, 122, 64, 64], "sticker1" ].  (So `placed_stickers` is a list of lists).

Then when painting the window, iterate through `placed_stickers`, blitting each one:

```
# paint screen
window.fill( background_colour )
for placement in placed_stickers:
    position, sticker_name = placement
    sticker_image = stickers[ sticker_name ]
    window.blit( sticker_image, position )  # <<== paint each sticker
```

If there's an option to erase a sticker, it should be pretty easy to iterate through the same list, finding which rectangle was clicked in by testing collision against the mouse point.